# Calculate rolling average of simulated data series with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am simulating a price time series, where the time horizon basically is that each month consists of 20 working days and 12 months are one year. I now would like to calculate the rolling average of this price, always based on the first day of the month.

I do have a working solution, but would like to know if there's a more elegant or faster one.

```
   dt.oil.price
   Period Month Day.Month  Oil.Price Oil.Supply Risk.Free.Interest
1:      1     1         1 39.4560000         NA         0.08642857
2:      2     1         2  3.7889460         NA         0.08642857
3:      3     1         3 51.0748751         NA         0.08642857
4:      4     1         4 60.6282853         NA         0.08642857
5:      5     1         5 35.7267224         NA         0.08642857
6:      6     1         6 26.1868977         NA         0.08642857
7:      7     1         7 32.6488136         NA         0.08642857
8:      8     1         8 42.6397549         NA         0.08642857
9:      9     1         9 18.8969991         NA         0.08642857
...
20:     20     1        20  8.8036135         NA         0.08642857
21:     21     2         1  2.5559526         NA         0.08642857
22:     22     2         2 24.3996401         NA         0.08642857
...
40:     40     2        20 41.2988566         NA         0.08642857
41:     41     3         1 20.8012327         NA         0.08642857
42:     42     3         2 70.5297726         NA         0.08642857
```

Just to give you an idea on the structure of the data. To create the above data structure with 60 periods:

```
set.seed(1);
dt.oil.price <- as.data.table(cbind( Period = 1:60, 
                                     Month = as.integer(rep(1:(60/20), each = 20))[1:60], 
                                     Oil.Price=rnorm(3*20,mean = 50, sd = 10)))

dt.oil.price[,"Day.Month" := rank(Period),by="Month"]
```

With the following code I can then select all first days of a month and calculate the mean of the oil price for these days:

```
 dt.oil.price[ Day.Month == 1, mean(Oil.Price)]
```

In the next step I use another helper column "Num.Months" to rank the number of months accordingly, by

```
 dt.oil.price[Day.Month == 1 & Period <= 8921,"Num.Months" := rank(-Period)]
```

and with this I can then select only the last two months for the average calculation, by subsetting this

```
dt.oil.price[Day.Month == 1 & Period <= 8921,"Num.Months" := rank(-Period)][Num.Months <= 2, Oil.Price]
```

A code snippet, which allows to calculate the mean without using an explicit helper column for the last three months:

```
dt.oil.price[Day.Month == 1 & Period <= 60, {Num.Months = rank(-Period); list("Period" = Period, "Month" = Month, "Oil.Price" = Oil.Price, "Num.Months" = Num.Months)}][Num.Months <=12, mean(Oil.Price)]
```

I hope my steps are all clear and it becomes also clear, what I would like to achieve. It is also possible to calculate the moving average dynamically by defining for example a period and then calculate the moving average for the last 12 months preceding that period. This can be achieved, by sub-setting the data.table only to periods smaller than the defined period and then calculating "Num.Months" for this data.table subset.

Comment: Showing an excerpt of your data always helps. However, providing the code how you did simulate you data, e.g. `set.seed(1); dt.oil.price <- as.data.table(cbind(Period=1:3*20, expand.grid(Month=1:3, Day.Month=1:20), Oil.Price=rnorm(3*20,mean = 50, sd = 10)))`, is even better to get people working on your problem.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code. BTW, `num.periods` is not specified. Don't forget `set.seed`.

Comment: This are assumption I make in this simulation, that there are five working days a week and four weeks a month. The requirement, that only the first day of the month is considered is based on a SEC rule, that for the valuation of oil and natural gas resources the companies should use the average of the price on the first day of the preceding 12 months. I use this moving average to calculate the PV-10 of a portfolio of oil wells.